# provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express

I have deployed one vb.net desktop application and sql server is used for backend. It is properly working on local machine but when accessing database from remote machine it giving the error in the title.

I have done these things already:

1. Started SQL server, sql browser service using sql server configuration manager.
2. added the sql server, browser exe in to firewall allowed program list.
3. restarted sql server and browser.
4. enabled TCP/IP, Shared memory, Named pipes in SQL server configuration manager
5. enabled the remote connection for this DB in database property

Comment: Can you verify the username that is being sent to the database? If your using Windows authentication then your local machine has you but the remote machine may be logging in as someone else that does not have security access to the database.

Comment: No I am using Windows Authentication

Comment: try not using windows auth and pass your username and password in from the app connection string, if it connects remotely with the username and password that you know for a fact works then its an issue of passing an app id to the database for remote connecting. You would make a generic app id and password on the database and lock down its functionality to only relevant items to complete the app tasks